# Python Selenium select a drop down option and hit submit

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried the examples specifically that I have found that are related to this question and they don't appear to work? Can someone point me in the right direction if I'm missing something here's the HTML. I'm basically just trying to select the 'low' option from the drop down and hit submit.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
        <p>Security Level is currently <em>high</em>.<p>
        <p>You can set the security level to low, medium or high.</p>
        <p>The security level changes the vulnerability level of DVWA.</p>

        <select name="security">
            <option value="low">low</option><option value="medium">medium</option><option value="high" selected="selected">high</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="seclev_submit">
    </form>
```

Here's the code that I have:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='security']/option[@value='low']").click()
```

I've tried these ways try to get the submit button to work:

```
driver.select_by_value("//select[@id='security']").click()
driver.find_find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

Any pointers?

Update:

This appeared to work but now I can't confirm as to why? I added the addtional information to go to a new page and then this stopped working?

```
driver.get('http://dvwa/security.php') 
el = driver.find_element_by_name('security') 
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):     
    if option.text == 'low':         
        option.click()  
driver.find_element_by_name('seclev_submit').click()
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='security']"))
select.select_by_value("low")


#Check for XSS
driver.get('http://dvwa/vulnerabilities/xss_r/')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("name")
elem.send_keys("<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>")
```

Comment: Seems this is what you are looking for: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver

Comment: What if you try using?   
find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='security']/option[text()='low']").click()

Answer (score 0):

`Select` is a class which is used to work on dropdown. Please try following:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='security']"))
select.select_by_value("medium")
```

or you can also create `select` object by name of element like:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("security"))
```

For more details, please go [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#navigation-history-and-location)

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work....Not the cleanest solution but I found that it works.....

```
driver.get('http://dvwa/security.php')
driver.implicitly_wait(15) 
el = driver.find_element_by_name('security') 
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):     
  if option.text == 'low':        
    option.click()  
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='security']"))
select.select_by_value("low")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.find_element_by_name('seclev_submit').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```